# Why does Collectors.counting reduce into a long?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--:

> ```
> public static <T> Collector<T,?,Long> counting()
> ```
>
> Returns a `Collector` accepting elements of type `T` that counts the number of input elements. If no elements are present, the result is 0.
>
> **Implementation Requirements:**
>
> This produces a result equivalent to:
>
> ```
> reducing(0L, e -> 1L, Long::sum)
> ```

Why does this Collector collect into a long? Is it because it can be optimized on various platforms where `typedef size_t uint64_t`? Or am I missing something? Is there a practical use for a Stream with more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number of elements are more than **Integer.MAX** value then adding up will wrap on the int max value, which will make total sum value (number of elements) wrong.

We generally write results in long where the result involves addition of elements.

**In short,** provided long return type to give support for all cases (number of elements less than Integer.MAX and greater than Integer.MAX both).

Comment: I was just confused about why any stream would contain two billion elements. And then I tried counting past Integer.MAX and [it barely took a second](https://ideone.com/MKyD2N). Now I see.

Comment: @ShioT empty loops are not useful for determining the performance, as it is too easy to optimize them away. It’s better to use something that could provide an answer to an actual question, e.g. `long c = LongStream.range(0, 10_000_000_000L).filter(l -> l%3 == 0).count(); System.out.println(c);`. In theory, this could still get optimized, but it’s rather unlikely due to its little relevance to real life applications.